# How to add Placeholder to Joomla User registration frontside screen

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, registration

I am creating one Joomla project where I need customize registration and login page and as per clients design I have to put Placeholder in text box.

can anyone guide me. How i can do this ?

I am trying to achieve this by overriding com_users component.

Answer (score 1):

Add "hint" to "registration.xml" (components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml)

Original field:

```
<field
            name="name"
            type="text"
            description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_DESC"
            filter="string"
            label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_LABEL"
            required="true"
            size="30"
        />
```

Changed:

```
<field
            name="name"
            type="text"
            description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_DESC"
            filter="string"
            label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_LABEL"
            required="true"
            size="30"
            hint="Enter your name here . . "
        />
```